# No such entity with customerId = 1

Tags: magento, magento2

I have a magento 2.3.2  and tried to do the order.After completing the order,success page is not redirected.But the order has created. Can anyone tell what will be issue.  Below I'm getting in error log

```
main.CRITICAL: No such entity with customerId = 1 {"exception":"[object] 
(Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\NoSuchEntityException(code: 0): No such entity 
with customerId = 1 at /opt/magento/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Exception/NoSuchEntityException.php:50)"} []main.CRITICAL: No such entity with customerId = 1 {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\NoSuchEntityException(code: 0): No such entity with customerId = 1 at /opt/magento/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Exception/NoSuchEntityException.php:50)"} []main.CRITICAL: No such entity with customerId = 1 {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\NoSuchEntityException(code: 0): No such entity with customerId = 1 at /opt/magento/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Exception/NoSuchEntityException.php:50)"} [](END)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please apply this patch in 2.3.2 https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/magento/magento2/pull/25307.diff

Or upgrade to 2.3.4

Source: https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/25307

Comment: Answers that contains only links will be delete in future so please post your answers with code and its explanation.

Comment: It's ok, i cannot post all the diff patch content.

Comment: How would you apply this patch?

Answer (score 0):

Apply this patch:

```
diff --git a/app/code/Magento/Checkout/Model/Session.php b/app/code/Magento/Checkout/Model/Session.php
index a654c78853d7..4a4861fa9ccd 100644
--- a/app/code/Magento/Checkout/Model/Session.php
+++ b/app/code/Magento/Checkout/Model/Session.php
@@ -7,6 +7,8 @@
 
 use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface;
 use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
+use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
+use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface;
 use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote;
 use Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteIdMaskFactory;
 use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
@@ -21,9 +23,6 @@
  */
 class Session extends \Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager
 {
-    /**
-     * Checkout state begin
-     */
     const CHECKOUT_STATE_BEGIN = 'begin';
 
     /**
@@ -228,7 +227,7 @@ public function setLoadInactive($load = true)
      *
      * @return Quote
      * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
-     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
+     * @throws NoSuchEntityException
      * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
      * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
      */
@@ -273,21 +272,17 @@ public function getQuote()
                          */
                         $quote = $this->quoteRepository->get($this->getQuoteId());
                     }
-                } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $e) {
+                } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
                     $this->setQuoteId(null);
                 }
             }
 
             if (!$this->getQuoteId()) {
                 if ($this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn() || $this->_customer) {
-                    $customerId = $this->_customer
-                        ? $this->_customer->getId()
-                        : $this->_customerSession->getCustomerId();
-                    try {
-                        $quote = $this->quoteRepository->getActiveForCustomer($customerId);
-                        $this->setQuoteId($quote->getId());
-                    } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $e) {
-                        $this->logger->critical($e);
+                    $quoteByCustomer = $this->getQuoteByCustomer();
+                    if ($quoteByCustomer !== null) {
+                        $this->setQuoteId($quoteByCustomer->getId());
+                        $quote = $quoteByCustomer;
                     }
                 } else {
                     $quote->setIsCheckoutCart(true);
@@ -375,7 +370,7 @@ public function loadCustomerQuote()
 
         try {
             $customerQuote = $this->quoteRepository->getForCustomer($this->_customerSession->getCustomerId());
-        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $e) {
+        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
             $customerQuote = $this->quoteFactory->create();
         }
         $customerQuote->setStoreId($this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId());
@@ -558,7 +553,7 @@ public function restoreQuote()
                 $this->replaceQuote($quote)->unsLastRealOrderId();
                 $this->_eventManager->dispatch('restore_quote', ['order' => $order, 'quote' => $quote]);
                 return true;
-            } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $e) {
+            } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
                 $this->logger->critical($e);
             }
         }
@@ -588,4 +583,22 @@ protected function isQuoteMasked()
     {
         return $this->isQuoteMasked;
     }
+
+    /**
+     * Returns quote for customer if there is any
+     */
+    private function getQuoteByCustomer(): ?CartInterface
+    {
+        $customerId = $this->_customer
+            ? $this->_customer->getId()
+            : $this->_customerSession->getCustomerId();
+
+        try {
+            $quote = $this->quoteRepository->getActiveForCustomer($customerId);
+        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
+            $quote = null;
+        }
+
+        return $quote;
+    }
 }
diff --git a/app/code/Magento/Checkout/Test/Unit/Model/SessionTest.php b/app/code/Magento/Checkout/Test/Unit/Model/SessionTest.php
index 26234992e613..969631901adf 100644
--- a/app/code/Magento/Checkout/Test/Unit/Model/SessionTest.php
+++ b/app/code/Magento/Checkout/Test/Unit/Model/SessionTest.php
@@ -9,7 +9,8 @@
  */
 namespace Magento\Checkout\Test\Unit\Model;
 
-use \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session;
+use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session;
+use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
 
 /**
  * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
@@ -374,6 +375,68 @@ public function testGetStepData()
         $this->assertEquals($stepData['complex']['key'], $session->getStepData('complex', 'key'));
     }
 
+    /**
+     * Ensure that if quote not exist for customer quote will be null
+     *
+     * @return void
+     */
+    public function testGetQuote(): void
+    {
+        $storeManager = $this->getMockForAbstractClass(\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface::class);
+        $customerSession = $this->createMock(\Magento\Customer\Model\Session::class);
+        $quoteRepository = $this->createMock(\Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface::class);
+        $quoteFactory = $this->createMock(\Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory::class);
+        $quote = $this->createMock(\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote::class);
+        $logger = $this->createMock(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface::class);
+        $loggerMethods = get_class_methods(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface::class);
+
+        $quoteFactory->expects($this->once())
+             ->method('create')
+             ->willReturn($quote);
+        $customerSession->expects($this->exactly(3))
+             ->method('isLoggedIn')
+             ->willReturn(true);
+        $store = $this->getMockBuilder(\Magento\Store\Model\Store::class)
+             ->disableOriginalConstructor()
+             ->setMethods(['getWebsiteId', '__wakeup'])
+             ->getMock();
+        $storeManager->expects($this->any())
+             ->method('getStore')
+             ->will($this->returnValue($store));
+        $storage = $this->getMockBuilder(\Magento\Framework\Session\Storage::class)
+             ->disableOriginalConstructor()
+             ->setMethods(['setData', 'getData'])
+             ->getMock();
+        $storage->expects($this->at(0))
+             ->method('getData')
+             ->willReturn(1);
+        $quoteRepository->expects($this->once())
+             ->method('getActiveForCustomer')
+         ->willThrowException(new NoSuchEntityException());
+
+        foreach ($loggerMethods as $method) {
+            $logger->expects($this->never())->method($method);
+        }
+
+        $quote->expects($this->once())
+             ->method('setCustomer')
+             ->with(null);
+
+        $constructArguments = $this->_helper->getConstructArguments(
+            \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session::class,
+            [
+                'storeManager' => $storeManager,
+                'quoteRepository' => $quoteRepository,
+                'customerSession' => $customerSession,
+                'storage' => $storage,
+                'quoteFactory' => $quoteFactory,
+                'logger' => $logger
+            ]
+        );
+        $this->_session = $this->_helper->getObject(\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session::class, $constructArguments);
+        $this->_session->getQuote();
+    }
+
     public function testSetStepData()
     {
         $stepData = [
```

Comment: How would you apply this patch?

Comment: You can apply this patch manually. Check the file name and function name regarding changes.